# Read from a file and strcat in to a variable in C

Tags: c

I am reading from a file and saving everything in a variable called `buff`. If I print out `buff` using printf, it prints out everything just fine. I have tried concatenating `result` with other strings/string-variables, and it works just fine. But as soon as I strcat/strncat `buff` with `result`, it goes into a never-ending loop (It doesn't print anything and the program never finishes). I have no idea why.

```
read(fd[0], buff, 1000);
strcat(result, buff);
```

I have tried this as well, but no luck

```
int n = read(fd[0], buff, 1000);
strncat(result, buff, n);
```

And this way,

```
read(fd[0], buff, 1000);
strncat(result, buff, sizeof(buff));
```

Comment: strncat's first argument is destination buffer, so therefore the third argument should be derived from its size, not the source's size (as you've done in your third example).

Comment: I have tried putting in the buffer size as the third argument. It still does not work. It goes into a never-ending loop. It doesn't print anything and the program never finishes.

Comment: Can we see a more complete example of your C source-code, such as where and how do you declare result?

Comment: @slevy1, thanks for mentioning that. There was a problem with how I declared the `result`. It is working now.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has no value to future readers on SO — there is no explanation of the mistaken declaration of the variable, and the code is abusing `strncat()` horribly as well (still). There are worse interfaces than `strncat()` — `gets()` for one — but not many.  It is fiendishly hard to use correctly; none of the code in the question is remotely correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is important to know more about the C source-code of the OP, such as where and how the variable result is declared. If there is a problem with how **result** is declared, then that might well  be the reason that the code is behaving in such an odd fashion.

In a subsequent comment, the OP explained:

> There was a problem with how I declared the result. It is working now.